# Finding the no of leaf nodes

Tags: data-structures, tree

An N-ary tree has N sub-nodes for each node. If the tree has M non-leaf nodes, How to find the no of leaf nodes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all if the root is level `0`, then the `K`-th level of the tree will have `N^K` nodes. You can start incrementing a counter level by level until you get `M` nodes. This way you will find how many levels is the tree consisting of. And the number of leaf nodes is the number of nodes on the last level - it is `N^lastLevel`.

Here is an example: `N = 3, M = 4`.

```
First level = 3^0 = 1
Second level = 3^1 = 3
1 + 3 = 4
```

So we found that the tree has two levels(counting from 0).
The answer is `3^2 = 9`.

Note: You can find the level number also directly, by noticing that `M` is a sum of geometric progression: `1 + 3 + 9 + 27 ... = M`

Hope it is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Mathematically speaking the nodes increase in the geometric progression.

0th level - 1
1st level - n
2nd level - n ^2
3rd level - n ^ 3
....
mth level - n ^ m

So the total number of nodes at m-1st level is 1 + n + n^2 + .. + n ^ m-1.

Now there is a good formula to calculate 1 + a + a^2 + a^3 + ... + a^m , which is 
(1 - n^(m+1))/(1-n), lets call this quantity K.

Now what we need is the number of leaf nodes which is n ^ m, and what we have is K. i.e. total number of non-leaf nodes. Doing some mathematical formula adjustment you will find that
n ^ m  =  **K *(n-1)  + 1.**

e.g. Lets say in 3-ary tree the total number of non-leaf nodes are 40, then using this formula you get the total number of leaf-nodes as 81 which is the right answer.